# How to apply styles to an element not containing a particular class in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply styles to a parent element if only it doesn't contain a certain class child element in CSS. To make it understand better, I have made a demo,

```css
.level-1 {
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}

.level-3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class='level-1'>
      <div class='level-2'>
          <div class='level-3'>This is text 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='level-1'>
      <div class='level-2'>
        <div class='level-3'>This is text 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='level-1'>
      <div class='level-2'>
        This is text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example scenario, I want all the elements under *level-1* to take a `width` of `400px` but if *level-1* contains *level-3* class name element, then I don't want the width of `400px`.
I tried using the `:not` selector but couldn't do it, I tried doing like this,

```
.level-1:not(.level-3) {
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}
```

I know I can do it via `classList.contains` in `Javascript` but I want to do it via `CSS`. Is there a way in which I could achieve the above requirement?

Comment: This is what the `:has()` pseudo-class is for. Unfortunately, it's not yet supported in any browsers. It's in jQuery, though.

Comment: You should be able to alter the style of the `div` elements those are parents (or grand parents) of child elements having class `.level-3` by JS through DOM API. i.e. `element.parentElement.style.width = "200px"`.

Answer (score -1):

You could add another class in level 1 class to be more specific with your CSS selectors i.e. to apply width specific to those div elements which does not have a level-3 class name  element.

```css
.level-1.include {
        width: 400px;
        background: green;
      }

      .level-3 {
        background: green;
        color: white;
        font-size: 32px;
      }
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="level-1 include">
        <div class="level-2">
          <div class="level-3">This is text 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="level-1">
        <div class="level-2">
          <div class="level-3">This is text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="level-1 include">
        <div class="level-2">This is text 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```